# What is meant or being referenced by the DOLLARS, CENTS and MILLICENTS terminology in substrate?

Tags: substrate, polkadot

Many substrate cryptocurrencies contain code referencing `DOLLARS`, `CENTS` and `MILLICENTS`, eg:

```rust
    pub const UNITS: Balance = 10_000_000_000;
    pub const DOLLARS: Balance = UNITS;       // 10_000_000_000
    pub const CENTS: Balance = DOLLARS / 100;      // 100_000_000
    pub const MILLICENTS: Balance = CENTS / 1_000; // 100_000
```

(see:
[kusama](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/8a6af44/runtime/kusama/src/constants.rs#L21-L24),
[polkadot](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/8a6af44/runtime/polkadot/src/constants.rs#L21-L24),
[rococo](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/8a6af44/runtime/rococo/src/constants.rs#L21-L24),
[westend](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/8a6af44/runtime/westend/src/constants.rs#L21-L24))

I am struggling to grasp what these terms are meant to reference.

- Because `DOLLARS` is originally set to the constant value of `UNITS` (eg: 10 billion for polkadot), my inference is that the term is meant to describe total supply at genesis. Is that correct? If so, it begs the question why the `DOLLARS` constant wasn't named `TOTAL_SUPPLY_AT_GENESIS` to avoid the ambiguity of the chosen term. Perhaps I've misunderstood what the term is referencing.
- I have completely failed to develop an inference for what `CENTS` and `MILLICENTS` are supposed to represent. Because of their conventional meaning in fiat currency, I initially assumed they refer to a fractional monetary unit however, most substrate currencies assign a value to `CENTS` and `MILLICENTS` that doesn't provide logical support for that inference. eg for polkadot:

  ```
  pub const CENTS: Balance = DOLLARS / 100; // 100_000_000
  ```

  or kusama:

  ```
  pub const CENTS: Balance = UNITS / 30_000;
  ```

  I find it unfortunate that cent is used in this manner in substrate codebases since

  > Etymologically, the word 'cent' derives from the Latin word centum meaning hundred

  ([wikipedia:Cent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cent_(currency))) and don't get me started on `MILLICENTS`.

I would really appreciate some clarification on what these terms mean in the substrate context.

Answer (score 0):

> my inference is that the term is meant to describe total supply at genesis. Is that correct?

I think DOLLARS never was the total amount of token at genesis.

As far as I know DOLLARS is just a unit for an amount of token, not related to any other specific currency named dollar.

a CENTS in polkadot is DOLLARS/100 so it is logic.

in kusama, CENTS is UNITS/30_000, IMHO in this case CENTS refers to the cent of an unnamed token unit which worth: UNITS/300, but I agree is a bit weird that this unit is not named.